# Is it unsafe to send a user's username and email in the url?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a website where the user can input their username, email, and password on the home page to create their account, then they click "Create Account" and it goes to a php script which checks if any are blank, if a username is taken, and so on, pretty standard stuff. If there is an error when creating the account, would it be unsafe to redirect the user back to the home page with their username and email in the url to fill the inputs back in?

Comment: I don't think any potential harm but I would avoid it using post method instead of get.

Comment: @KonstantinosTsourdinis I don't get how does POST help here? The OP wants to redirect the user to another page if registration fails.  The problem is not about how to submit the registration form in the first place, but how to pass along the failed username and email to the new page. Plz explain further.

Comment: Just use AJAX post to validate. You can redirect or stay with a message

Comment: why don't you use SESSION instead of get method to take user data back to home page

Comment: You could just store the username and email in the users browser using cookies: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case, sessions would work best:

```
session_start();
...
//if username or email taken, save in session
$_SESSION['taken_name'] = $username;
$_SESSION['taken_email'] = $email;

//redirect user
header('Location: home.php');
```

Then retrieve the value at **home.php**

```
session_start();
... 
$username = $_SESSION['taken_name']? : null;
$email = $_SESSION['email']? : null;
```

You can then use `$username` and `$email` wherever you need them on the home page.

Generally speaking though, it's ok to include username in the URL so long as this is public information on your site. In most cases this is information displayed to the public (it's how users see one another).  Many of the biggest sites, including `facebook` and `twitter` will even allow users to create custom URLs with their name.  If you're running a site for which even the username is meant to be private (users don't see one another), then don't put it in the URL.

Email is another matter. Email addresses are typically considered private, so I wouldn't include them in a URL. It opens the user to even more spam as URL links get scrapped all the time.

Comment: Alright, this makes sense and seems like a much better way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should never have such data like username and email. I'd suggest you to use sessions instead.

The page where you're redirecting(let's assume it's check.php), make sure you store the data and status in the session.

**Checking page:**

```
// check.php
/* If sign up fails */
$_SESSION['reg_fail'] = array(
    'username' => ....,
    'email'    => '....
);

header(Location:.....); // Redirecting to the home page
```

**Home page:**

```
session_start();    // Write this on top of the page.
 /* Other code */

<input name="username" value=<?php echo @$_SESSION['reg_fail']['username'] ?>>
<input name="email" value=<?php echo @$_SESSION['reg_fail']['email'] ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is to use the `$_GET` method after the form has been submitted. Make use of the `value` attribute on your input tag. Having any sensitive information in the URL is not secure.

Example

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $_GET['input_name']; } ?>"
```

This is assuming your PHP script redirects back after validation to display any errors.